# FROM clause on MDX query does not filter a cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

Here is the query

```
    WITH
    Member [Measures].[Total] AS
    ([Measures].[m1],[04 TT].[04 Country].[All])

    sELECT
    {
    [Measures].[M1],
    [Measures].[Total]
    }
    ON columns,

    ([01 Date].[01 Y-M].[01 Month].allmembers*
    [04 TT].[04 Country].allmembers*
    [02 SKU].[02 SKU NAme].&[Tea]
    )
    ON rows

    FROM (SELECT ( STRTOSET("[18 Nets].[18 NetName].&[4307]", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM ( SELECT (STRTOMEMBER("[01 Date].[01 Y-M].[01 Month].&[201610]", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("[04 TT].[04 Region].&[39]", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Retail Analytics])))
```

and here is the result set

```html
<table>   
<tr><td>2016/October</td><td>All</td><td>Tea</td><td>49,995</td><td>51,942</td></tr>
<tr><td>2016/October</td><td>Russia</td><td>Tea</td><td>49,995</td><td>51,942</td></tr>
<table>
```

Can you explain me, that results is not one number.
Why the filter in the FROM clause does not partially work?
Why do the other filters on date and nets work?
How can I count m1 measure on all countries except that which does not fits the 
STRTOSET("[04 TT].[04 Region].&[39]", CONSTRAINED) filter?

Answer (score 0):

there are more than one question in your post!

for the first one, if you mean that why there are two rows in the result, it is because of using "allmembers" in the rows of your query like "[04 TT].[04 Country].allmembers" 
So if you change them to look like "[04 TT].[04 Country].&[04 Country]"  and "[01 Date].[01 Y-M].[01 Month].&[01 Month]" the result will be just one row.